# How to count the partitions for particular table?

Tags: database, oracle, partitioning

In Postgres I may use something like

```
select count(p1.*) from pg_partitions p1
where  p1.tablename = 'table_name';
```

How to write query that counts NO of partitions for specific table in oracle?
What is oracle equivalent of pg_partitions ?

Comment: Check `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS`

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which privileges you have

Partitions of a table you own

```
select count(*) from user_tab_partitions where table_name = yourtable;
```

Partitions of a table you own or you have privilege to see it

```
select count(*) from all_tab_partitions where table_name = yourtable and table_owner = ownerofthetable ;
```

If you have privilege `select any dictionary` or `select catalog role`, or a granted privilege over the specific `dba_tab_partitions`view , then

```
select count(*) from dba_tab_partitions where table_name = yourtable and table_owner = ownerofthetable ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped and saved me a lot of time! Have a good day

Comment: @Damianos17 you're very welcome ;)

Comment: One additional comment: if we are dealing with composite partitioned tables, then there is a second level below PARTITIONS, namely SUBPARTITIONS. You will still see partitions, and the SQL shown above works, but if you were after the number of physical segments representing your table then you need to use the view family of [DBA | ALL | USER]_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS. Just wanted to mention this for completeness.